# Why does my browser display the encoded html entity (e.g. &amp;amp;amp;amp;)?

Tags: php, html

I have a php page that displays customer's input, which I saved in mysql database. When the input is loaded, some html characters are displayed wrongly.
For example this url:

http://www.greenbook.club/shopjerry/index.php/014101201323

You can see that the browser actually displays & amp; not just &.

I tried to use `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `html_entity_decode`, but seems no impact.

The code is really basic, just:

```
<?php echo $description ?>
////I also tried this, but no difference
<?php echo html_entity_decode($description) ?>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at how this data is being saved. It appears that it's being encoded each time it's being saved without being decoded.

If you look at the rogue codes ie can&amp;amp;amp;#39;t which is originally the word can't.

```
On the first save the single quote in can't would be getting turned into &#39;

On the Second save that would then turn into &amp;#39; then &amp;amp;#39 and so on for each save.
```

SO the issue is with the process of saving the content from the editor into the Database. The content is being encoded when saved to the DB from the Editor but not decoded when loaded back from the DB into the editor.